# Virtual to Physical mapping

Tags: memory, arm, mapping, cortex-a

I am working on a Broadcom BCM2711, Quad-core Cortex-A72 (ARM v8) 64-bit SoC @ 1.5GHz.
I have a question: if i have two virtual/physical addresses like :

```
virtual: 0x55acd71000 physical: 0x28560000 with pfn: 165216
virtual: 0x55acd73000 physical: 0x28562000 with pfn: 165218
```

Are they mapped in the same DIMM, Rank, and bank?
Given two consecutive physical addresses can I say they are mapped in different rows of the same bank?

Thank you.

Comment: rank and bank mapping are part of the dram controller, do you have access to broadcom's (or more likely the controller IP they purchased) documentation?

Comment: @old_timer the mapping function is not documented

Comment: It is rare that it would be and then with anything Broadcom the odds are close to zero.  if you had the proper NDA with them you wouldnt be able to ask this kind of question anyway...You are not developing a board otherwise you would have it so this is a software question?  What is it you are you trying to do with this information?

Comment: @old_timer i need that information to access two given address in the same bank but different rows

Comment: why would software care?  unlikely there is more than one bank in that module but if so probably only two. you can look at the markings on the back and try to figure out the part, but the mapping you wont figure out without info on the ip that broadcom uses and how that breaks down, it is not necessarily something that is documented even internally.

Comment: I dont know how the arm could be fast enough to notice the difference, the gpu maybe, but it is more about math than memory.  so I dont think you would be able to figure it out experimentally assuming there would be a performance difference.

Comment: @old_timer i think the board has more than a single bank. but if two given addresses are consecutive can they be mapped in different bank ?

Comment: two banks is one address bit so the odds are extremly high, the bank bits would not be down that far as the width of the memory is 16 or 32 bits wide most likely but that is a combination of address to bank/ras/cas and how caching works.  cache line size and bursts.  if you are asking about byte addresses 0x16 and 0x18 they are likely going to be in the burst/transfer, basically, essentially same location.  but I dont know about this part, it wouldnt make sense would it to have addresses like that broken away from basically the same location, same row.

Comment: I have no access to that information though the best we are going to know is the dram specific if there are usable markings on the back.

Comment: There is one/some broadcom engineer that monitors the bare metal forum and sometimes we get some nuggets of info there, a good place to ask this question.

Comment: I think it goes back to "why would software care?". If there's an observable effect, you could possibly use it to find out empirically.